# Weird bug with a simple for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm currently trying to read this XML file (Note that I simplified the XML for simplicities sake):

```
<Users>
<User id="1" name="NY-01" location="New York">
<Hosts>
    <Host>
       <Host_Name>val9</Host_Name>
    </Host>
    <Host>
       <Host_Name>td8</Host_Name>
    </Host>
</Hosts>
</User>
</Users>
```

I used the JAXB library to read it.

So essentially I did a loop:

```
List<DataVal> l = new ArrayList<DataVal>();

for (int i = 0; i < data.getUsers().size(); i++) {
    DataVal pc = new DataVal();
    pc.setUser_id(data.getUsers().get(i).getId().toString());
    pc.setUser_name(data.getUsers().get(i).getName());
    pc.setUser_location(data.getUsers().get(i).getLocation());

    for (int j = 0; j < data.getUsers().get(i).getHosts().getHost().size(); j++) {
        pc.setHost_name(data.getUsers().get(i).getHosts().getHost().get(j).getHostName());
        System.out.println(pc);
        l.add(pc);
    }
}
```

Note that when I do the System.out.println(pc) right before adding to the list, the value for pc is correct;

But when I print the ArrayList "l" after this block of code, I'm getting the host_name td8 both times instead of val9 and td8 as the next one. The id, name, location values are correct though.

Why is this?

This is the code for printing the list:

```
for (int q = 0; q < l.size(); q++) {
    System.out.println(l.get(q)); // I have a toString implementation of this...
}
```

Edit: After debugging this with eclipse, for some reason after each iteration of the j loop, the values all change to the last loop value for host_name...

Comment: show the code where you print your `ArrayList`

Comment: what is data.getSites () ?  I don't see a Sites element in your XML

Comment: Sorry about that, was a typo from doing some editing. But essentially, I'm still confused why the value is correct when I print it inside the double for loop, but not when I print the list...

Comment: Looks like you are only creating one DataVal and adding it to the list repeatedly and you are overwriting the host name each time. You probably want to move all the code that creates and fills in your DataVal instance to inside the inner loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your are replacing pc.setHost_name on every pass, this means that your host name value will be equal to the last reading of a host.

If they need to be distinct, this means that you need to create your DataVal object inside the host loop, not the user loop.

Comment: You're correct. I just don't understand why for instance the data is getting overwritten in the j loop. The first iteration is stored currently, but the second add operation changes the first value as well as add the second in the list. Can you sort of elaborate?

Comment: Because your are using the same object reference